# Why is this simple HTML/ASP submenu not working?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a very simple two level menu, but the submenu items simply don't show up and I cannot figure out why, the code in question is so simple I must be missing something very fundamental but I cant see it

I tried removing everything apart from the bare minimum and I still cannot get it working

The code looks as follows

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
                Configuration <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Configuration">Main Configuration</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Basic Data</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a asp-controller="Languages" asp-action="index">Languages</a></li>                    
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

Been trying all morning what am I missing here?

Comment: Is that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` belongs to `true` value? Can you give some hint which part of submenu that not showing up in rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes the auth is true, the Languages lowest level menu item is not showed when hovering oer Basic Data or clicking Basic Data